# How do I provide Ethernet to a couple of servers that connects to WiFi using e.g. a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: linux, wifi, ethernet, bridge

I have good WiFi and a couple of servers that have Ethernet interfaces. I would like to use e.g. a Raspberry Pi to connect to my existing good WiFi and then provide Ethernet network access with a cheap Ethernet switch. I'd like to avoid NAT, since the other WiFi clients need to be able to see the servers on the Ethernet.

Part of my problem is that I'm not sure what such a setup is called. Is this a WiFi-Ethernet-bridge?

I've bought a [D-Link DAP-1620](https://www.dlink.com/en/products/dap-1620-ac1300-wi-fi-range-extender) "Wifi Extender" and it works most of the time, but it looses connectivity every 48 hours or so and requires a power-cycle... = Garbage.

But other than that, it does *excactly* what I need.

So I thought: How about using a Raspberry Pi?

I thought "Lets just setup a bridge between wlan0 and eth0", but it is not as simple as that, as pointed out in:

https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections#Bridging_with_a_wireless_NIC

That section goes on to document how to use `ebtables` and requires knowledge of every Ethernet host's IP and MAC addresses.

But is there a solution using e.g. a Raspberry Pi so that the WiFi-to-Ethernet bridge is completely transparent to the Ethernet hosts, so DHCP and every other protocol under the sun will work? Apart from needing periodic reboots (AARRRRRHHHH), the D-Link does it perfectly...

Similar posts:

- [How do I configure a network interface bridge from WiFi to Ethernet with Debian? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363332/how-do-i-configure-a-network-interface-bridge-from-wifi-to-ethernet-with-debian) - solution uses a straight up bridge which doesn't work as described in the debian wiki link above and there is a NAT solution.
- [networking - How can I most simply transparently bridge traffic between wlan0 and eth0? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151194/how-can-i-most-simply-transparently-bridge-traffic-between-wlan0-and-eth0) - with a NAT solution.

Comment: TL;DR: Wifi is not Ethernet. If your RPi is an Access Point, you can consider bridging Wifi with Ethernet. If your RPi is a STAtion client, forget it, Wifi itself (not RPi nor Linux) makes it very difficult and requires support from the actual AP (and the RPi).

Comment: See this Q/A where I made an answer and especially the network engineering link in it, about why it's different from Ethernet, what are those 3 MAC addresses or even 4 MAC addresses in Wifi when Ethernet uses only 2: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/554331/theoretical-tap-interface-w-wifi-parent-interface/555676#555676 .